# Definition conflicts with previous value - StorageGetDownloadURLTask.swift

Tags: swift

I am getting an error in Xcode when trying to build an app.
In Firebase Storage-StorageGetDownloadURLTask.swift.

Firebase Storage: 11.0.7
Flutter: 3.0.5
Xcode 12

In a few lines it presents the information:

> "Definition conflicts with previous value.
> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'count'.
> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'components'"

[image]

I would like to understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it.

I already updated Firebase Storage version from 11.0.1 to 11.0.7.
I removed the podfile.lock.
I removed the Pods.
Flutter clean command, then flutter pub get.
Pod install, pod deintegrate, pod update.

And I wasn't successful.
I'm trying to update the version of my app from flutter 2.2.3 to flutter 3.0.5, I managed to run it on Android, but in Xcode it's showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The line `downloadTokens = dictionary["downloadTokens"]` is declaring a constant named `downloadTokens` with a type of `Any?`.

The line `guard let downloadTokens = downloadTokens as? String` is trying to  declare a constant named `downloadTokens` with a type of `String`.

So you are trying to create two separate constants with the same name but different types, hence the error message of "*Definition conflicts with previous value*".

Change your code to:

```
guard let downloadTokens = dictionary["downloadTokens"] as? String,
    downloadTokens.count > 0 else {
```

This combines your two lines into one creating a single constant named `downloadTokens` with a type of `String`.

This fix will resolve the other two errors since `downloadTokens` is not correctly of type `String` instead of `Any?`.